# Stuck on boot ubuntu 18.04 5.3.0-59-generic

Tags: boot, 18.04, amd-ryzen

Last night, I did `apt-get update` and `upgrade`, and when tried to enter to system it got stuck on boot and then show me this error :

```
failed to start load/save screen backlight brightness of acpi_video0
```

If I add `nomodeset` I can boot and enter but with very low resolution. Is there any solution? I have a  HP PAVILION 15-CW0053LA . Meanwhile im using 5.0.0-37-generic to enter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Boot to Recovery Mode, if required.

Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

or

`sudo pico /etc/default/grub`

Find:

```
"quiet splash"
```

Change it to:

```
"quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Or:

```
"quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`